# Build path in Rad

Tags: java, rad, buildpath

I have 10 projects in my ear project. I am using RAD. There is a web project in the same ear. I want to add few project to the build path of web project. I added it and it does not work but when I create a jar of the project and place it in WEB-INF/lib it works.

What could be the issue?

Thanks
Mahi

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue. It is supposed to work this way, check [J2EE Class Loading Demystified](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0112_deboer/deboer.html)